# Cucumber "OR" clause?

Tags: cucumber, automated-tests, calabash

Is it possible to specify some kind of "OR" (alternative) clause in Cucumber?

I.e. if I have two valid responses to some event I would like my test to pass if either of them happens.

Something like that:

```
"When I press a button"
"Then I should see the text 'Boo'"
"Or I should see the text 'Foo'"
```

My particular scenario is a login screen. When I try to log in with some random password, I should see an error message "invalid password" if the server is working or a message "network error" if it is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OR is not supported. You can use Given, When, Then, And and But. Please refer to http://docs.behat.org/en/v2.5/guides/1.gherkin.html

But perhaps you could make use of the But keyword to achieve what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can't really define OR functionality using the Gherkin but you can pass in a list and check that one of the values in the list matches what was returned.

Define list:

```
Then the greeting service response will contain one of the following messages
      |Hello how are you doing?|
      |Welcome to the front door!|
      |How has your day been?|
      |Come right on in!|
```

Check list:

```
    @Then("the get messages service response will contain one of the following messages")
    public void text_matching_one_of_the_following(List<String> greetingMessages){
        boolean success = false;
        for(String message : greetingMessages){
            assertTrue(textMatchesResponse(message));
        }
    }
```